# How to find the exact individual count of array of string in array of sentences efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, trie

How to find the exact individual count of array of string in array of sentences efficiently?

**Example**

```
var names= ["jhon", "parker"];
var sentences = ["hello jhon", "hello parker and parker", "jhonny jhonny yes parker"];

Answer : jhon ->1 times (do not consider jhonny), parker-> 3 times.
```

**what i am doing :**

```
var lenObj ={};
for(let i=0; i< sentences.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<name.length; j++){
        // split the sentences element and compare with each word in names array. And update the count in lenObj; 
    }
}
```

**Using RegEx:** I am using \b for boundry. 
But the problem is dynamically I am not able to assign the value: so `"/\b+sentences[i]+"\b/gi"` is not working

```
for(let i=0; i< sentences.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<name.length; j++){
        var count = (str.match("/\b+sentences[i]+"\b/gi") || []).length; // is not working
        // if I hardcode it then it is working (str.match(/\bjhon\b/gi));
    }
}
```

But i feel like above solutions are not efficient. If there any way we can do this more efficiently and optimized way?

Comment: parker-> 4 times???

Comment: @Ele I suppose it's the total from both arrays. That's the same for jhon -> 2 times

Comment: @Cid I see 3 parker.

Comment: @Ele 3 parker in `sentences` + 1 in `names`

Comment: @Cid umm got it

Comment: Why not use HashMap ?

Comment: @Ele soory parker is 3 times only.I will update it

Comment: Why `jhon` twice, then? It only occurs once

Comment: @CertainPerformance my bad it is only 1 time.

Comment: All the below answers are working perfectly. But we are restricted to upvote 1 answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the strings and filter by name and get the length of the array.

```js
var names = ["jhon", "parker"],
    sentences = ["hello jhon", "hello parker and parker", "jhonny jhonny yes parker"],
    parts = sentences.join(' ').split(/\s+/),
    result = names.map(name => parts
        .filter(s => s === name)
        .length
    );

console.log(result);
```

Linear time complexity:

- create an object with the wanted names as key and zero as value for counting,
- get `sentences` joined to a single sting,
- split this string
- iterate the parts and check if a part is a key of count, then increment count.

```js
var names = ["jhon", "parker"],
    sentences = ["hello jhon", "hello parker and parker", "jhonny jhonny yes parker"],
    counts = names.reduce((o, n) => (o[n] = 0, o), {});

sentences.join(' ').split(/\s+/).forEach(s => {
    if (s in counts) counts[s]++;
});

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: What is the time compexity in this approach ?

Comment: looks like O(n*m). do you like to get a linear compexity?

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works when the sentences are composed *only* of possible names and spaces. It sounded like OP wanted a word boundary test (which would, for example, work with `hello jhon.`)

Comment: Yeah https://jsfiddle.net/7pxz8L1k/ but whether that's actually a possibility to factor in or not is up to OP

Comment: @NinaScholz can pls describe how it is linear. Some how  I dint get it ?

Comment: @NinaScholz what changes should we do for ignore cases so that it can match with jhon as well as JHON ?

Comment: just normalize the string to lower case before splitting `sentences.join(' ').toLowerCase().split(...`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the object `RegExp` for dynamic expressions, along with the functions `map` and `reduce` for counting.

```js
let names= ["jhon", "parker"],
    sentences = ["hello jhon", "hello parker and parker", "jhonny jhonny yes parker"],
    result = names.map(n => sentences.reduce((a, s) => a + (s.match(new RegExp(`\\b${n}\\b`, "g")) || []).length, 0));

console.log(result);
```

Linear complexity approach

```js
let names= ["jhon", "parker"],
    sentences = ["hello jhon", "hello parker and parker", "jhonny jhonny yes parker"],
    words = sentences.join(" "),
    result = names.map(n => (words.match(new RegExp(`\\b${n}\\b`, "g")) || []).length);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: is this also a linear time solution?

Comment: @DirtyMind no, this is an *O(n * m)*

Comment: @DirtyMind added a linear complexity approach

Answer (score 2):

Create the regular expression by surrounding each name with `\b`, joining by `|`, then passing to `new RegExp`. Then you can iterate over each sentence, and each match for that pattern, and put each match on an object that counts the number of matches for each name:

```js
var names= ["jhon", "parker"];
var sentences = ["hello jhon", "hello parker and parker", "jhonny jhonny yes parker"];
const pattern = new RegExp(names.map(name => `\\b${name}\\b`).join('|'), 'gi');

const counts = {};
for (const sentence of sentences) {
  for (const match of (sentence.match(pattern) || [])) {
    counts[match] = (counts[match] || 0) + 1;
  }
}
console.log(counts);
```

Comment: What is the time compexity in this approach ?

Comment: It will iterate over every character in each of the sentences exactly once, testing against a character at an index in `names`, so that's `O(n * m)`, where `n` is the length of the `names` and `m` is the combined length of the `sentences`. This works for the generic problem, but if the substrings to be searched for always have a particular and/or if the haystacks to be searched have a certain format, this can be reduced (such as in the other answer)

Comment: Best part in this solution is its taking care of `hello jhon.` or `hello jhon!` but is also working for `hello jhon@gmail.com`